# Redirect Events in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a `MyUserControl` in which I have `Button1` and `Button2` buttons.

I need to "delegate" that button clicks to the MyUserControl's `Button1Click` event and `Button2Click` event respectively.

Bellow is a stub I don't really know finishing...

```
  Private WithEvents Button1 As Button
  Private WithEvents Button2 As Button

  Public Custom Event Button1Click As Eventhandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
      AddHandler Me.Button1.Click, value
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
      RemoveHandler Me.Button1.Click, value
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
      Me.Button1.Invoke(???)
    End RaiseEvent
  End Event
```

I wonder if I need the `WithEvents` in the buttons declaration, and how to achieve the `RaiseEvent` part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your setup correct, you might want to just handle the events and pass them on to a custom event. Like this:

```
' This is defined in your control
Public Event Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

' Other stuff here

' This is the handler for the Button1.Click Event.
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Raise our custom event to the outside
    RaiseEvent Button1Click(Me, e)
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

What happens here is a simple relaying of events, it breaks the event-chain and fires it's own event in between.

```
MyUserControl
 +-> Custom Event: Button1Click
 +-> Control: Button1
```

Now if `Button1` gets clicked, the event chain is looking like this:

```
Button1.CLick() -> Calling EventHandlers
 +-> MyUserControl.Button1_Click(Object, EventArgs) -> Raises its own Event
      +-> Parent.MyUserControl_Button1Click(Object, EventArgs)
          ' Application Logic executes here
```

Comment: what will be if I'd use an `AddHandler myUserControl.Button1Click, AddressOf myMethod`? Will I be subscribed to the mouse Clicks on that button? Not sure...

Comment: @serhio: Yes, that should work. Because `myUserControl` receives that hardwired `Button1.Click` Event and passes it as it's own on.

Comment: @serhio: Why are you surprised?

Comment: @Bobby: For me, this behavior should favorize the propagation of event *from* source (Button1) but not also *to* it...

Comment: @serhio: I can't follow, sorry. What I did here was a simple event-relaying. I'll edit my answer to make clear what I mean.